# Deploy did not succeed: Deploy directory 'out' does not exist

Tags: deployment, next.js, netlify

When deploying an app created with Next.js to netlify, the following error occurs and the deployment fails.

```
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  6. Deploy site                                                
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
​
​
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  Configuration error                                           
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
​
  Error message
  Deploy did not succeed: Deploy directory 'out' does not exist
​
  Resolved config
  build:
    command: yarn build
    commandOrigin: config
    publish: /opt/build/repo/out
  plugins:
    - inputs: {}
      origin: config
      package: '@netlify/plugin-nextjs'
    - inputs: {}
      origin: config
      package: netlify-plugin-cache-nextjs
Caching artifacts
Started saving node modules
Finished saving node modules
Started saving build plugins
Finished saving build plugins
Started saving yarn cache
Finished saving yarn cache
Started saving pip cache
Finished saving pip cache
Started saving emacs cask dependencies
Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
Started saving maven dependencies
Finished saving maven dependencies
Started saving boot dependencies
Finished saving boot dependencies
Started saving rust rustup cache
Finished saving rust rustup cache
Started saving go dependencies
Finished saving go dependencies
Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
Failing build: Failed to build site
Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
Finished processing build request in 1m25.310488139s
```

The various files and settings are shown below.

**netlify.toml**

```
[build]
  command = "yarn build"
  publish = "out"

[[plugins]]
  package = "@netlify/plugin-nextjs"

[[plugins]]
  package = "netlify-plugin-cache-nextjs"
```

**package.json**

```json
...
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "next start",
  "export": "next export"
},
...
```

**Netlify | Build settings**
[image: congif]

The various settings are based on the following pages.

- [Failed during stage 'building site': Deploy directory 'out' does not exist - Support - Netlify Community](https://community.netlify.com/t/failed-during-stage-building-site-deploy-directory-out-does-not-exist/30986/10)
- [Next.js on Netlify | Netlify Docs](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/common-configurations/next-js/?_ga=2.167785641.929602931.1614175758-1995773659.1608391628)

If you know how to solve this problem, please let me know.
I'm open to any ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `yarn export` (or just `next export`) in the build command inside your `netlify.toml` file. Since `next export` doesn't get called, the `out` folder will not exist.

```
[build]
  command = "next build && next export"
  publish = "out"

...
```

Comment: yarn export is not a valid command.

Comment: Just use the Next CLI directly in the command: `next build && next export`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 6):

Also you may need to add `target: 'serverless'` to your `next.config.js` file.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't used Nextjs with Netlify before, but I think Next's default build directory is `.next`. This might be there reason your deployment failed. However, you can use a custom destination for your build.

```js
module.exports = {
  distDir: 'out',
}
```

*Reference https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/setting-a-custom-build-directory*

Answer (score 0):

if you got Deploy did not succeed: Deploy directory 'dist' does not exist error:

change the build command on `package.json` to `nuxt generate` or in the netlify build settings use `nuxt generate` instead of using `yarn build` in the build command.

then set `target: 'serverless'` on `nuxt.config` file.

Comment: The question is about Next.js not Nuxt