# NextJS on Netlify: Deploy did not succeed; Deploy directory 'out' does not exist

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js, netlify

I am currently developing a website and am hosting it on Netlify. Up until a recent change, It has been deploying with no issues. However, I pushed a change and suddenly, I get this error; `Deploy did not succeed: Deploy directory 'out' does not exist`.
I know that there are many similar questions on here and other forums, but I have tried those solutions and their combinations with no success.
**Sources that I viewed:**

- [Deploy did not succeed: Deploy directory 'out' does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66353549/deploy-did-not-succeed-deploy-directory-out-does-not-exist)
- https://answers.netlify.com/t/failed-during-stage-building-site-deploy-directory-out-does-not-exist/30986
- https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/troubleshooting-tips/?_ga=2.156848827.1277875653.1616642374-301736030.1616521229

Here is the GitHub repository: https://github.com/henrikvtcodes/henrikvt.com-nextjs-old
**Things I have tried:**

- adding `"export":"next export"` to the package.json and changing my build command to `next build && next export`
- adding `"export":"next build && next export"` to the package.json and changing my build command to `npm run export`
- The standard `npm run build`
- Many more (can be seen in the commit history on GitHub)

All of these have either failed with the aforementioned error code or exit code 1.

I have no idea what to do. The standard `npm run build` command runs perfectly fine on my local system as well. Another piece of potentially useful information; I test-deployed the same repository on Vercel and that worked perfectly (somewhat as expected) but I'd rather use Netlify for multiple reasons.

Comment: What build command do you have in your deploy settings in Netlify?

Comment: Currently, it's set to `npm run build`

Comment: Try changing it to `next build && next export`. You need to run the export command on Netlify, otherwise the `out/` folder doesn't get created.

Comment: the build failed with exit code:1. I am not sure if I have to import a module to handle it?

Comment: `Command failed with exit code 1: next build && next export`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a *next.config.js* add `target: serverless` to it. The file will look something like this:

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  future: {
    webpack5: true,
  },
  target: 'serverless'
}
```

What you can then do is add a `netlify.toml` file to the root of your project to tell Netlify it should run the build command like so:

```
// netlify.toml
[build]
  command = "yarn build"
```

This made my Next.js deploys to Netlify work.

Comment: Adding target: 'serverless' worked for me, Thank you.